# Amazon says I'm not passing cookies, but I am

Tags: nginx, cookies, nginx-reverse-proxy

Okay, so, I'm basically creating a website where users can shop on Amazon but route their delivery through us. The best way to do this would be to reverse proxy Amazon, and then hook onto the shopping cart during checkout.

Problem: I've got everything setup right, my reverse proxy works, but when I try to add items to card, Amazon gives me:

> Important messages about items in your Cart: Please Enable Cookies in
>   your Web Browser to Continue.
>
> Learn more about cookies and how to enable them.
>
> Once you have enabled cookies, please click here to continue shopping.

Trouble is, I'm already passing cookies:

```
proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;
proxy_pass_header  P3P;
```

I know this is possible since I've seen multiple other websites doing something similar, and when comparing my cookies with them, I see them to be the exact same.

See the full configuration file [here](https://gist.github.com/amingilani/50e9b32cd0c2a06b3ec25c6c2d2401ee)

### Update

I tried using `proxy_cookie_domain` but it didn't work either:

```
proxy_cookie_domain amazon.com localhost:3000;
proxy_cookie_domain .amazon.com .localhost:3000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are automatically passed by nginx both ways, you don't have to modify its behaviour to continue to pass cookies.

However, what's probably going on is a mismatch between the `Domain` and/or the `Secure` attribute of the cookie, hence, your browser either does not accept the cookie, and/or does not send it due to a non-secure connection and/or domain mismatch.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

> `Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Domain=<domain-value>; Secure`

If it's a domain issue, you could use [`proxy_cookie_domain`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cookie_domain) to address it.

Comment: I tried that a while ago, as well. I thought the same thing, it didn't work. See the update in my question for the code.

Comment: Nevermind, I wasn't using the directive properly. Thank you!